# Expected 0 arguments, but got 1. with Redux toolkit

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I am currently trying to build a simple example of redux using redux/toolkit. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

This is my store.

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import reducer from "./workouts";

export default function () {
  return configureStore({ reducer });
}
```

Here is my workouts.ts file

```
import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export interface IWorkout {
  id: number
  restTime: number
  workoutTime: number
  exercises: number[]
  numReps: number
}

export interface IState {
  workouts: IWorkout[]
}

export interface IAction {
  type: string
  payload: IWorkout[] | any
}

export const workoutAdded = createAction('workoutAdded')
export const workoutDeleted = createAction('workoutDeleted')

const defaultState: IState = {
  workouts: [],
}

let lastId = 0

const reducer = (state: IState = defaultState, action: IAction): IState => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case workoutAdded.type:
      return {
        ...state,
        workouts: [
          ...state.workouts,
          {
            id: ++lastId,
            restTime: action.payload.restTime,
            workoutTime: action.payload.workoutTime,
            exercises: action.payload.exercises,
            numReps: action.payload.numReps,
          },
        ],
      }
    case workoutDeleted.type:
      return {
        ...state,
        workouts: state.workouts.filter((workout) => workout.id !== action.payload.id),
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default reducer
```

And here is my index.ts file

```
import { render } from "react-dom";
import configureStore from "./store/store";
import { workoutAdded } from "./store/workouts";
import App from "./App";

const store = configureStore();

const newWorkout = {
  restTime: 10,
  workoutTime: 30,
  exercises: [1, 2, 3],
  NumReps: 6
};

store.dispatch(workoutAdded(newWorkout));

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

My error appears in index.ts file in this line:

```
store.dispatch(workoutAdded(newWorkout));
```

Not sure what I am missing. I reproduced the error in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-hellman-qmkep?file=/src/index.tsx:0-411)

This is the error that I am getting in the console:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

workoutAdded has 0 arguments, if you want to add arguments, you can implement Action

```
export class workoutAdded implements Action {
  readonly type = "workoutAdded"
  constructor(public payload: Workout){}
}
```

Comment: I want to add parameters, when dispatching the action in the index.ts file

Comment: I just changed my answer, does that work as intended now?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue. createAction can receive as a second argument a callback function that returns an object with the payload.

```
export const workoutAdded = createAction("workoutAdded", (workout) =>{
    return { payload: workout }; 
});
```